# Event tracking form submissions - why do i have to click twice?

Tags: jquery, forms, google-analytics

I'm new to jQuery and analytics event tracking. I'm looking to track form submissions. My logic here is that the user will click "submit", and the form waits to submit until its had time to get sent to Google's servers.
The tracking is working but you have to click submit twice. Any advice? Thanks a bunch in advance.

```
   jQuery("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submission',location.pathname);
  jQuery(this).unbind('submit');
    setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery(this).submit();
}, 200);
```

});

I'm under the impression you must prevent the submission for a few seconds in order to allow the "gif" to get sent to Google.

Here is the URL if this helps: 
http://salisburyrugby.com/recruit-contact/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using setTimeout, use Google's built-in callback function, [hitCallback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback):

```
jQuery("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submission', location.pathname,{
    'hitCallback' : function(){
       jQuery(this).submit(); 
     }
  }
});
```